# How to filter a model and join on User model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models. First one is `User` model in app `accounts`, another one is `Records` model in app `activities`. I want to show user list with a count of their activities for different actions filtered by date range on `date_and_time`

```
#models.py file in "activities" app
from acccounts.models import User


class Records(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Record"
        verbose_name_plural = "Record"

    activity_choices = (('Solved', 'Solved'), ('Closed', 'Closed'),
                        ('Escalated', 'Escalated'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

I expect something will print in my template output like:

```
 Name     |   Solved   |   Closed   |   Escalated
----------------------------------------------------
 Hasinoor |        120 |         35 |             9
----------------------------------------------------
 James    |         92 |         32 |            17
----------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to select model you mainly want to use and then using reverse relation annotate count filtering it via `Case`

```
User.objects.all().annotate(records_count=Count(Case(
        When(
             records__date_and_time__range=['2011-01-01', '2019-01-01'], 
             then=1
        ),
    output_field=IntegerField(),
)))
```

To make fields you want for different types you can use multiple `Count` in annotation, and to filter on both date and type in `When` you can use [Q expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q) or multiple `When` expressions in [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case).